# Is "mad" used as an intensifier in the UK?

Tags: british-english, colloquialisms, intensifying-adverbs

I mean mad as in 'mad good' 'mad props' etc which mean ''very good'' or ''much propers to you'' or intensifies the ''good'' part. I hope its more clear now?

Comment: In order to gauge how *mad* is being used in your examples, it's necessary to know what you intend "mad good" and "mad props" to mean. While I've tidied up what you have written, I don't know how to add what you have not.

Comment: Apologies, I edited it with what I meant.

Comment: What research have you done to answer this question yourself? Do you think we’re mad keen to do people’s work for them?

Comment: "Mad" is certainly used as an intensifier in Britain, but not in quite the direct way you suggest. People don't normally say something was "mad good". But they often use "mad about" e.g. "My brother is mad about football", "mad about cycling" etc. Sometimes you will hear that someone is "mad keen". e.g. Will you be coming out with us on Saturday?" "Yep, I'm mad keen to do that".

Comment: to be mad about something meaning to like it is not just British English.

Comment: I've searched the net and often results are unclear to me and my WiFi is slow, sorry...

Answer (score 1):

Wiktionary defines the usage as an intensifier as mainly NE US.

***[Mad:](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/mad)***

> (slang, chiefly Northeastern US) Intensifier, signifies an abundance or high quality of a thing; very, much or many.
>
> - I gotta give you mad props for scoring us those tickets.   Their lead guitarist has mad skills.   There are always mad girls at those parties.

The following extract from [Wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/mad-as-an-intensifier.2173277/)  sheds more light on this usage:

> Like "crazy" and "wicked", "mad" describes an extreme condition in itself, so it doesn't seem unnatural for it to be used as an intensifier for the same purpose: "Furiously, with excessive violence or enthusiasm; to the point of madness. Now usually in weakened sense, as an intensifier: greatly, excessively, extremely, very." [OED]
>
> It was most often used with "angry" and "drunk"—which can be more literally associated with madness, but there are examples, admittedly not highly colloquial in the way that modern usages are, such as "mad lonely" (1935) and "mad afraid" (1895). And then there is a quotation from New York magazine from 1994, strikingly similar to the 1895 usage:
> When they first bring me [to prison], man I was mad scared. Mad scared.

Comment: Weird that can here intensify a noun not just an adjective. *Mad skills*